# Many piezo crystals driven by Pi?

Tags: gpio, electronics

I'm considering starting a new RPI project that will end up being a haptic feedback suit for video games. My thought process so far is that I can embed a lot of piezo crystals inside a vest / jacket of some sort, and control those from a Raspberry Pi. The only problem is that I'm not super great with interfacing a Pi with hardware devices (motors, speakers, etc.)

I'd assume I'll need something to sit between the Pi and the piezos, to provide an AC current, enough power, and probably protect the Pi from any electrical currents coming back from the crystals.

Is there some sort of hat or other device I could use for this purpose? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly do you expect the crystals to do?

Comment: @jsotola my idea was that they'd be able to provide vibrations as haptic feedback.

Comment: crystals produce very small deflection

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, piezo devices are thin and light, so can only generate the higher audio frequencies (a few kHz).

Haptic feedback needs to be lower in frequency, so the devices generally used in phones (Eccentric Rotating Mass, Linear Resonant Actuators, and Voice Coil Motors) are electro-magnetic instead of piezo. Search for these, and you'll get advice on the electronic circuitry to drive them.